# Django test failes ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base' in github actions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, github-actions

i am trying to put down a CI/CD workflow using github action for my project. i have created some test which run fine locally. but on github actions it fails with an error. i have given it the env variables it ask for in the error but still it isn't working link to the repo https://github.com/Suryansh5545/Ticketify. This is the workflow https://github.com/Suryansh5545/Ticketify/actions/runs/5729864155. After fixing this i am gonna try to make workflow to make and export the images from my compose file and then run staging on portainer.

Error given by workflow:-

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'


   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'event'
```

It also says about CELERY_BROKER_URL not being a attribute but it is set in both github environment variable and by default if not present in settings.